# Expecting "," or ")", found "nvarchar2"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, import, sql-loader

Here is my SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Fri Nov 10 00:39:56 2023
OS=UBUNTU 20

I am trying to load data from csv file with the help of following code:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1) 
LOAD DATA 
INFILE '/home/oracle/airports.csv'
INTO TABLE airportDemoData 
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
(
country nvarchar2(48),
country_code varchar2(2),
city nvarchar2(48),
city_code varchar2(3),
airport nvarchar2(84),
airport_code varchar2(3)
)
```

Here is sample of my csv file:
[image: CSV FILE]

Here is my sqlldr command running in oracle user:
`sqlldr login/pass control=airport.ctl LOG=airport.log`

Here is the error that I am facing:

```
 SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Fri Nov 10 00:39:56 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 7.
Expecting "," or ")", found "nvarchar2".
country nvarchar2(48),
        ^
```

Please help me to point out where I am making mistake

Best Regards

Comment: Perhaps you want to review the control file reference, particularly the field definition part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NVARCHAR` is not a valid SQL Loader data type. SQL Loader datatypes do not map 1:1 to database column data types. For a delimited file, you must use `char`.

See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1151

On using VARCHAR:

> VARCHAR A VARCHAR field is a length-value datatype. It consists of a
> binary length subfield followed by a character string of the specified
> length. The length is in bytes unless character-length semantics are
> used for the data file. In that case, the length is in characters. See
> "Character-Length Semantics".
>
> VARCHAR fields can be loaded with correct results only between systems
> where a SHORT data field INT has the same length in bytes. If the byte
> order is different between the systems, or if the VARCHAR field
> contains data in the UTF16 character set, then use the appropriate
> technique to indicate the byte order of the length subfield and of the
> data. The byte order of the data is only an issue for the UTF16
> character set.
>
> ...
> VARCHAR data cannot be delimited.

And CHAR:

> CHAR The data field contains character data. The length, which is
> optional, is a maximum length. Note the following regarding length:
>
> - If a length is not specified, then it is derived from the POSITION
>   specification.
> - If a length is specified, then it overrides the length in the POSITION
>   specification.
> - If no length is given and there is no POSITION specification, then
>   CHAR data is assumed to have a length of 1, unless the field is
>   delimited:
>
>   - For a delimited CHAR field, if a length is specified, then that length
>     is used as a maximum.
>   - For a delimited CHAR field for which no length is specified, the
>     default is 255 bytes.
>   - For a delimited CHAR field that is greater than 255 bytes, you must
>     specify a maximum length. Otherwise you will receive an error stating
>     that the field in the data file exceeds maximum length.

So your field specification should look something like this:

```
(
country char(48),
country_code char(2),
city char(48),
city_code char(3),
airport char(84),
airport_code char(3)
)
```